# Spark label truncating issue - spark label text becomes truncated if there is plus sign character in it

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

Why does spark label text becomes truncated if there is plus sign in it. Here is the code of a simple app. The issue is reproduced both in Adobe Flex SDK 4.6 and in Apache Flex SDK 4.12:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        >
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:VGroup width="350">
        <s:Button id="button" width="100%"
                   content="jkqUP+e8Cu62ALgLjkqUPea8Cu62ALgLjkqUPea.aa8Cu62ALgLjkqUPe8Cu62ALgLjkqUPea8C"/>
        <s:Label maxDisplayedLines="1" text="jkqUP+e8Cu62ALgLjkqUPea8Cu62ALgLjkqUPea.aa8Cu62ALgLjkqUPe8Cu62ALgLjkqUPea8C" width="100%" />
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

The label text becomes truncated both in the Button label and in Label after "+" character though there is enough space.

Comment: Since you set the VGroup width as 350 the calculated textWidth is greater than the width of the label and also the maxDisplayedLines is 1 so the label get truncated, but i'm not sure why it is always truncating after the '+' symbol.  try setting 100% width for VGroup.

Comment: I debugged the SDK code and the problem seems in Label.as getTruncationPosition method (line 1527 in 4.6 SDK).   This method always returns the position after "+" character. You can try and change the position of "+" in the string and see the result.

Comment: yes there is some thing wrong with the Flash player textLine(flash.text.engine.TextLine) in getAtomWordBoundaryOnLeft which returns true when it detects the "+" symbol but when we give empty space after ("+ ") it works fine.

Comment: The "+" symbol creates the line break in the text line which cause this behaviour.

Comment: Does anyone come with the solution with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set the style lineBreak="explicit" for spark label which fix the issue. By default it is "toFit". For button add a style tag or set lineBreak in skin if you have one.

```
<fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
        s|Button s|Label
        {
            lineBreak:explicit;
        }
    </fx:Style>

<s:Label lineBreak="explicit" />
```

Comment: lineBreak="explicit" requires manually inserting line breaks into string, because the text used in label will not be static and each time it will require to calculate the width of visible text which is unfavorable.

Comment: Do you want the label to display multi-line text when there is no space to display it?